# Using new line(\n) in string and rendering the same in HTML

Tags: jquery, html, string, newline

I have a string say

```
string display_txt = "1st line text" +"\n" + "2nd line text";
```

in Jquery, I am trying to use

```
('#somediv').html(display_txt).css("color", "green")
```

quite clearly I am expecting my msg to be displayed in 2 lines, but instead \n is being displayed in the message. Any quick fixes for that?

Thanks,

Comment: Quite clear, answer is in your question, you are trying to render the error message in div as html, so you can use `<br />` tag

Comment: There is nothing "quite clear" in expecting two lines. On the contrary, it is quite clear that the newline will be rendered as plain space, only wrapping the line if needed. It is how HTML works, of course it is also how `.html` works.

Comment: I just meant with the context where i have stored my string as "1st line text" and "2nd line text" , it was clear that i want these in 2 lines, not with respect to how html works:) thank you.

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9726970/how-to-preserve-newlines-when-showing-a-text-file-with-jquery

Answer (score 85, accepted):

Use `<br />` for new line in html:

```
display_txt = display_txt.replace(/\n/g, "<br />");
```

Comment: for some reason, I've to escape the "\n" as "\\n" or else it doesn't work. (tested in Chrome 46). Any reason why?

Comment: Please note that this will only replace the first occurence of the `\n` character inside the string. See the [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)

Comment: best `.replace(/\n/g, "<br />")` is prevent more newline.

Comment: I think @vsync 's answer should be the accepted one.

Comment: Worked perfectly. Thank you.

Comment: @SujayPhadke for some reason it's just printing `\n` as text when I try to escape :-(

Answer (score 200):

Set your css in the table cell to

```
white-space:pre-wrap;
```

```js
document.body.innerHTML = 'First line\nSecond line\nThird line';
```

```css
body{ white-space:pre-wrap; }
```

Comment: so isn't this supposed to be the accepted answer? LE: I see that this is only supported in IE 8+ [link](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_text_white-space.asp)

Comment: This answer is way better than setting the innerHTML, because it doesn't cause a XSS vulnerability.

Comment: Besides, you can use `white-space:pre-line;` as sequences of whitespace will collapse into a single whitespace. Text will wrap when necessary, and on line breaks. More information on: [https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_text_white-space.asp](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_text_white-space.asp)

Comment: This answer does not convert \n within text to a newline

Comment: @ste_irl - what do you mean? the `\n` means a new line should be printed and it does print it

Answer (score 11):

You could use a pre tag instead of a div. This would automatically display your \n's in the correct way.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
         var display_txt = "1st line text" +"\n" + "2nd line text";
         $('#somediv').html(display_txt).css("color", "green");
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<pre>
<p id="somediv"></p>
</pre>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe `.text` instead of `.html`?

Answer (score 0):

I had the following problem where I was fetching data from a database and wanted to display a string containing `\n`. None of the solutions above worked for me and I finally came up with a solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61484190/7251208