# How to write newline using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, string, newline

There is a formatted txt file that my java program reads and sends over the contents as a string to front-end.
The string that is sent to front end looks like this:

```
var result = "This is the result.\nIt contains some details\n\nDetails are as follows\nabc,xyz"
```

In the frontend, This data must be written to a div in the following format:

```
This is the result.
It contains some details

Details are as follows
abc,xyz
```

Using the following code did not work:

```
$("#divId).html(result);
```

Alternates like val(), text() did not work either. 
How can I make the browser write the new lines in the div when displaying the result?

Comment: You can use `<br>`

Comment: Highlight the text and view the source: it has newlines. You are looking for an html `<br>`, not a newline.

Comment: Java is to javascript as car is to carpet.  And for a laugh: http://stackoverflow.com/a/245073/870729

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8573890/using-new-line-n-in-string-and-rendering-the-same-in-html

Comment: <br> helped for the text. Thank you! The file also has some formatted table content. This was written to the file using String.format(). Is there a way to retain that formatting when writing the result in front-end?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
  $('#divId').html("<pre>" + result + "</pre>");
```

Comment: `<pre>` has a specific semantic meaning. It is not a lazy way to avoid HTML tags.

Comment: it means this text is preformatted, leave it as is. it can be further customized with another font, and css. i don't think it's that bad. he still should html encode the message though.

Comment: You're confusing display and semantics: https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/grouping-content.html#the-pre-element

Comment: and am i supposed to read that thing because someone who thinks he knows everything better said so. i'm not confusing anything, you just don't have respect.

Comment: Using <pre> helped retain the formatting of the tables that were present in the text file. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Convert the line breaks to `<br>`s

```
$("#divId).html(result.replace(/\n/g, "<br />"));
```

Comment: Beat me to it. :)

Comment: Need to make it global otherwise it will works on first new line only

Answer (score 0):

Let's consider a simple HTML source file.

```html
Hello

2 new lines.



3 new lines.
```

Let's consider another one:

```html
Hello<br>The magic of HTML tags!
```

You are confusing newlines with HTML `<br>` tags.

Answer (score 0):

Use like this

```
var result = "This is the result.\nIt contains some details\n\nDetails are as follows\nabc,xyz" 
var res = result.replace(/\n/g, "<br>");
$("#divId).html(res);
```