# Line break inside string (React Native)

Tags: javascript, react-native

I'm developing an app where at some point app receives a string from Facebook Graph API.

String looks like that:

```
"Some text some text, some text.\n\nMore text and more\n\nAnd little bit more".
```

How can I replace \n\n with line break what actually works in code?

I know how to replace this with something:

```
var ret = stringToReplace.replace('\n\n','<br />');
```

But how can i replace it with working line break. I have tried to replace with '\n' '\r\n'. Every replacement just acts like usual text. For example:

```
"Some text some text, some text.<br />More text and more<br />And little bit more"
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I test the following code and it works. You should just wrap your text in a `<Text>` component.

```
export default class App extends React.Component {
  text = "Some text some text, some text.\n\nMore text and more\n\nAnd little bit more"

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text>
          {this.text}
        </Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

The result of this code is like this:
[image]

Comment: Yes, this solution works, when i enter my text manually, but in my app this text comes from Facebook Graph API and i can't change it manually.

Answer (score 14):

I know I am pretty late to the party but I recently stumble across the same problem when I was fetching data with `\n` from a database. The solution that worked for me was just to run the `replace` method and replace incoming `\n` with jsx `\n`. So in your case it would be:

```
var ret = stringToReplace.replace(/\\n/g,'\n');
```

Looks like a really stupid solution but it worked for me.

Comment: @contrl What happens is that `\n` is initially interpreted as a string when it is fetched from the database. However, when calling `replace`, `\n` can then be perceived as a new line.

Comment: this is pretty weird, but it actually did the trick for me.

Comment: @KevinHGriffith I still don't fully grasp the mechanism underlying this behavior but thanks for your answer :)

Comment: @contrl sorry for not being able to fully explain why it works. Glad I could help you out though. :)

Answer (score 1):

React/ React native has line break object `` {`\n`} ``, see below code sample

```
<Text style={{margin: 10}}>
 Our Address {`\n`}

xxx, Clear Water Bay Road {`\n`}
Clear Water Bay, Kowloon {`\n`}
HONG KONG {`\n`}
Tel: + xx {`\n`}
Fax: + xx {`\n`}                    
</Text>
```

Comment: This works well, thanks! My only comment is that you don't really need the backticks, since you're not doing any variable evaluation - single quotes would be sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

Use template literals/backticks as wrapper instead of double-quotes. It worked for me.